# I'm successfully using a random background image script but would also like to add an image specific background position as well

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently using this successfully:

```
<script>
    var imgCount = 15;
        var dir = 'wp-content/themes/Stoq/home-images/';
        var randomCount = Math.round(Math.random() * (imgCount - 1)) + 1;
        var images = new Array
                images[1] = "1.jpeg",
                images[2] = "2.jpeg",
        images[3] = "3.jpeg",
        images[4] = "4.jpeg",
        images[5] = "5.jpeg",
        images[6] = "6.jpeg",
        images[7] = "7.jpeg",
        images[8] = "8.jpeg",
        images[9] = "9.jpeg",
        images[10] = "10.jpeg",
        images[11] = "11.jpeg",
        images[12] = "12.jpeg",
        images[13] = "13.jpeg",
        images[14] = "14.jpeg",
        images[15] = "15.jpeg",
        document.getElementById("random-bkg-img").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dir + images[randomCount] + ")";
   </script>
```

However, with each image I would like to be able to assign a background image position. So each image would have a url, plus either a class or inline css to give each random image an adjustable background-position.

Just not sure how to accomplish that so that these two values are associated with each image.

I've searched for a solution for a couple hours and couldn't find anything like this. The expectation is that I can add the background position to each image.

Comment: Try using an object instead of an array, then each item in the object (JavaScript equivalent of a multi dimensional array) can have an image object containing the url, alignment, etc for the image.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you give me an example of what you are referring to? I'm not sure how this would look .

Comment: @user23872617: For example: `images[1] = { file: "1.jpeg", someOtherKey: "some other value" }`  When multiple values are associated with each other to describe a single multi-faceted concept, that generally describes an object with properties on it.  The rest of the code would then use properties from the object.  For example: `"url(" + dir + images[randomCount].file + ")"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered assigning them to an object rather than directly to an array, and then selecting them randomly using Math.Random?

```
let images = [
    { url: "1.jpeg", position: "center" },
    { url: "2.jpeg", position: "top left" },
    { url: "3.jpeg", position: "bottom right" },
];

let randomCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length); // Adjusted to match the length of the images array
let selectedImage = images[randomCount]; 

let elem = document.getElementById("random-bkg-img");
elem.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + dir + selectedImage.url + ")";
elem.style.backgroundPosition = selectedImage.position;
```